# Clear content from a certain cell to the end of the document

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

What is the code to clear data from a certain cell to the end of the whole document?
For example, I have data in `D2` and I would like to write code in a button to clear all data from `D2` until the very end of the document.  My idea is that it would start as something like this:

```
Range("D2", `<i>whatever the end function is</i>`).Clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
Range("D2:D" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
```

Edit:

Per comments, to delete from `D2` to the end of the workbook (rows and columns), you can use this:

```
Range(Range("D2"), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents
```

Comment: I assume that's preferred over `Range([whatever]).Value = ""`?  Will ClearContents also clear out the formatting and any other "behind the scenes" stuff?

Comment: `ClearContents` will remove any values or formulas, but no formatting. Substitute with `Clear` if you want the formatting to be removed as well.

Comment: Is there any technical difference in using `.clearContents` over setting `.value = ""`? Should I use one over the other in my macros?

Comment: I would imagine they're roughly equivalent. I would probably use `Value` if I were setting all cells in the range to a non-blank value. If I wanted to clear the cell, I'd probably use the provided `Clear` or `ClearContents` functions.

Comment: Thanks @Bond - you've given me something to research and think about :D

Comment: Thanks @Bond, but this only cleared all of `D`, maybe I worded my question wrong.  How can I clear contents from `D2` to the very end of the document, rows and columns?

Comment: @TylerP - Gotcha. I added an edit to my answer to show how you can do this.